# Started Process error stream is empty

Tags: java, windows, process, stderr

I'm trying to control external process from java code like this:

```
String[] Args = { mPath, "\"" + filePath + "\"" };
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Args);
mProcess = pb.start();
```

Then i want to read something from **stderr**:

```
mError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    mProcess.getErrorStream()));
if (mError.ready()){
    //read
}
```

And ready() always returns false.

But after this:

```
pb.redirectError(Redirect.to(new File("c:\\err.log")));
```

All error messages can be found in err.log file.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: ...is there anything on stdout?

Comment: I didn't see that you attempted to read from the error stream

Comment: mError.ready() is false, means nothing to read

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it worked for me.

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(ARGS);
 builder.redirectErrorStream(true); // setting  true
```